# Redo previous request when the first fails with 401 Unauthorized

Tags: java, android, android-networking, retrofit

I'm building an Android application that will fetch data from a REST API.

To make the requests I'm using [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) together with [Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/).

For all my requests I add a RequestInterceptor that will add a header (Authorization) to all my requests.
In the RequestInterceptor I'm calling a method to the my current access_token then I populate the header to the request.

```
RequestInterceptor requestInterceptor = new RequestInterceptor() {

    @Override
    public void intercept(RequestFacade request) {
        Token token = TokenPreferences.getToken();

        request.addHeader("Authorization", token.getTokenType() + " " + token.getAccessToken());
    }
};

RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
      .setEndpoint("https://example.com")
      .setRequestInterceptor(requestInterceptor)
      .build();

  ...
```

This works fine until the access_token has expired, then the request will fail with HTTP status 401 Unauthorized.
When this happens, I want to make a new request to get a new access_token from my refresh_token I got and then do the first request again.

I'm not really sure how to make that work.

Comment: I've not used Retrofit, but from reading the documentation you should be able to throw an Exception from a common error handler. Catch the exception and request for a new token from the catch block. I'm unsure about what the best way to retry the request is in your case. If the framework itself does not have a mechanism to retry, perhaps you can make a recursive call to the same method that is limited to a depth of N retries.

Answer (score 2):

Try a `com.squareup.okhttp.Authenticator`. As far as I can tell, this is preferable to `com.squareup.okhttp.Interceptor` (which you'll find suggested elsewhere), because it will only kick in for unauthorized requests. Here's a basic example:

```
public class ApiAuthenticator implements Authenticator {

    @Override
    public Request authenticate(Proxy proxy, Response response) throws IOException {
        for (Challenge challenge : response.challenges()) {
            if (challenge.getScheme().equals("Bearer")) {

                String authToken = // Refresh the token here

                if (authToken != null) {
                    return response.request().newBuilder()
                            .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + authToken)
                            .build();
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Request authenticateProxy(Proxy proxy, Response response) throws IOException {
        return null;
    }
}
```

You can attach it to your client like this:

```
okHttpClient.setAuthenticator(new ApiAuthenticator());
```

Be aware that if you're using Retrofit to refresh your token and the token is invalid, you might get unexpected, hard-to-debug behavior for 403 codes, but the solution is just to use a try/catch block.

```
try {
    token = oauthService.refreshAccessToken(args);
} catch (RetrofitError error) {
    // Do something that leads to login
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Retry mechanizm is not implemented in Retrofit. It will be in v2. ([Retrying requests manually](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/572))

You should implement retrying by recursive call from onFailure() callback as [Deepack suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25389463/redo-previous-request-when-the-first-fails-with-401-unauthorized#comment39599195_25389463).

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue and I currently don't know how to retry my request after it failed due to a Unauthorized error.

Although **@Yuriy Ashaev** mentioned that the retry mechanism should be part of the v2.0 Retrofit version, this should be dedicated only to 5xx errors (see [Request Object draft description here](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/297)) and attempting to retry a request that failed for another reason will raise an exception.

As of now, you can still add your own ErrorHandler to your RestAdapter and catch the Unauthorized error to fetch a refresh token. Here is a way to achieve this:

```
class RestErrorHandler implements retrofit.ErrorHandler {

    @Override
    public Throwable handleError(RetrofitError cause) {
        Response r = cause.getResponse();
        if (r != null && r.getStatus() == 401) {

            Token token = mTokenProvider.fetchToken();
            if (token != null) {
                addHeader(HEADER_AUTHORIZATION, token.getToken_type() + " " + token.getAccess_token());
            }
            // Todo: Relaunch previous request
            return cause;
        }
        return cause;
    }
}
```

However I don't see any way to retry the failed request from this point other than in all your *failure()* request callback which will be called when returning the RetrofitError from your ErrorHandler...

I would really appreciate if someone could point us how you could retry the failed request from the ErrorHandler as the response only point to f-the request url.